# Is there efficient token generation in Black or White?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Is there any black or white cards that whenever opponent loses a life (or when I gain life) create a creature token?

I'm planning a combo with [Corpse Knight](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCorpse%20Knight%5d) and [Impassioned Orator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bImpassioned%20Orator%5d).

If so can you show me what set it is in. And if not can you tell me if there are any other combos I could use.

Comment: My quick Gatherer search indicates that no, there isn't.  The combo risk is probably too great.

Comment: This is off the question, but:
darkness + teysa,orzhov scion + sac outlet + any create, generates infinite ETB and LTB effects.
Add corpse knight, or impassioned orator and you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot think of anything that combos with them for as many iterations as you want. There are a number of effects that create tokens once per turn based on gaining/losing life.

In standard (as both cards you mentioned are standard legal):
[Regal Bloodlord](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=447359)
[Resplendent Angel](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=447170)

Outside of standard, the best I can find is:
[Crested Sunmare](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=430695)
[Regna, the Redeemer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=445971)
[Angelic Accord](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=438573)
[First Response](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=383239)

In general I think they are quite careful with this effect, and restrict it to happening once per turn specifically to not enable the combo that you're seeking.

Comment: First response is lose a life for yourself and thank you

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of cards that cause you to gain life for a creature entering the battlefield (examples: [Angelic Chorus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAngelic%20Chorus%5d), [Answered Prayers](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAnswered%20Prayers%5d), [Auriok Champion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAuriok%20Champion%5d), [Essence Warden](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEssence%20Warden%5d), [Ajani's Welcome](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAjani%27s%5d%2b%5bWelcome%5d), [Soul's Attendant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSoul%27s%5d%2b%5bAttendant%5d), [Soul Warden](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSoul%20Warden%5d)).  As a result, I seriously doubt Wizards would print a card that creates a token when you gain life.  See [this search](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3A%22whenever%20you%20gain%20life%22) for things that combo directly off of life gain.

Meanwhile, a lot of things cause life loss, (not the least of which being damage), so Wizards tends not to print things that trigger off of life loss.  See [this search](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3A%22whenever%20an%20opponent%20loses%20life%22) for how few results there are.

So to do this, you're going to need a three card combo.  Let's take a "when a creature enters the battlefield, gain life" as the first combo piece.  Here are some options (it's pretty hard to stay within white/black on this one):

- [Famished Paladin](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFamished%20Paladin%5d) and [Presence of Gond](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPresence%20of%20Gond%5d)
- [Searing Meditation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSearing%20Meditation%5d) and [Polyraptor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPolyraptor%5d)/[Sprouting Phytohydra](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSprouting%20Phytohydra%5d)
- [Well of Lost Dreams](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWell%20of%20Lost%20Dreams%5d) and [Hoofprints of the Stag](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHoofprints%20of%20the%20Stag%5d)

Alternatively, you could just go for effects that make a bunch of tokens:

- [Commander's Authority](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCommander%27s%5d%2b%5bAuthority%5d)
- [Bitterblossom](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBitterblossom%5d)
- [Akroan Horse](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAkroan%20Horse%5d)
- [Creakwood Liege](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCreakwood%20Liege%5d)
- [Endless Ranks of the Dead](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEndless%20Ranks%20of%20the%20Dead%5d)
- [Storm Herd](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStorm%20Herd%5d)
- [Assemble the Legion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAssemble%20the%20Legion%5d)

Answer (score 0):

PS - I will edit this later with link when I get home as currently at work.

The kind of strategy you are looking for is something that has been dubbed as an "aristocrat" deck.

The archetype relies on sacrificing your own creatures for value and is usually classified as aggressive. The original deck that did this was named aristocrats because two of its sacrifice outlets were [Falkenrath Aristocrat](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFalkenrath%20Aristocrat%5d) and [Cartel Aristocrat](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCartel%20Aristocrat%5d).

There is currently an Abzan version in standard as of M20 being released. Not sure how good this deck really is as I haven't tried but worth having a look at it.

Will post link and decklist later.

Answer (score -2):

I am currently making a really cheap budget deck in black/withe zombie token summoning.
[here's the link](https://deckstats.net/decks/125688/1288262-zombie-machine)

It is based on Reassembling skeleton and Ravenous harpy combo associated with some open the graves to spawn zombie tokens. Teysa Karlov doubles that number.

Then Vizier of the scorpion gives them deathtoutch while Graph harvest gives them menace.

I do not see why you can't make that deck with the cards you mentioned before.

Comment: Please give a breakdown of the deck so that we don't have to follow the link

Comment: //Main
1 Army of the Damned
2 Consecrate // Consume
1 Cradle of the Accursed
2 Ethereal Absolution
1 Fireshrieker
3 Graf Harvest
2 Kaya's Ghostform
1 Liliana, Dreadhorde General
2 Mortify
1 Ninth Bridge Patrol
4 Open the Graves
4 Orzhov Basilica
2 Orzhov Guildgate
1 Pitiless Plunderer
4 Plains
4 Ravenous Harpy
4 Reassembling Skeleton
11 Swamp
4 Teysa Karlov
4 Vizier of the Scorpion
2 Vorrac Battlehorns

Comment: Please edit that into the question